# JAVA Google App Engine + Facebook API + GSON = Trouble with Javabean

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, javabeans, gson

I am trying to get the user's friends list from Facebook.

The problem seems to be the Javabean...

```
FBUser fbuser = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, FBUser.class);



public class FBUser implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3154429420153433117L;

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    private Friends friendsList = new Friends();

    private FBUser() { }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Data> getFriendsList() {
        return friendsList.getData();
    }

    public static class Friends implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6991758772193514527L;

        private List<Data> data;

        private Friends() { }

        public List<Data> getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(List<Data> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public class Paging implements Serializable {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1689816298710621080L;

            private String next;

            private Paging() { }

            public String getNext() {
                return next;
            }

            public void setNext(String next) {
                this.next = next;
            }

        }

    }

    public class Data implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5008541658519841090L;

        private String id;
        private String name;

        private Data() { }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

}
```

Json:

```
json: {"id":"10861234","name":"Whatever","email":"whatever\u0040gmail.com","friends":{"data":[{"name":"Someone","id":"10861234"},{"name" ...43"}],"paging":{"next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/10861234\/friends..."}}}
```

The fields ID, Name and Email I can retrieve succesfully... but the friendsList is null... =(
Maybe it is the way I am trying to get it from the nested class, any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `friendsList` in your JSON (or, there's no `friends` in your Java class - whichever way you'd like to look at it). Gson silently ignores anything in the JSON that is not present in your classes.

You have a field `friends` whose value is an object. That object has a field `data` which is an array of objects and a field `paging` which is another object.

You need to write Java classes that match that structure. You're ... close.

In your `FBUser` class change:

```
private Friends friendsList = new Friends();
```

to:

```
private Friends friends = new Friends();
```

or:

```
@SerializedName("friends")
private Friends friendsList = new Friends();
```

Then in your `Friends` class you need to add:

```
private Paging paging = new Paging();
```

Also note that you don't have to initialize these values unless you specifically don't want them to be non-null when using these classes elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, I could properly solve my problem, thanks!